# How to reload a jQuery element when a button is pressed

Tags: jquery, chart.js, jquery-selectors

I have a button that generates a graph (using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/)):

```
<canvas id="graph"></canvas>

<script>
    $("#button").click(function() {
        let ctx = $("#graph");
        let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {/* My nice graph. */});
    });
</script>
```

But each time the button is pressed a new graph is created above the old graph. So then I have a lot of graphs. With jQuery I need to delete or empty the graph element and recreate it everytime the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destroy it first like so:

```html
<canvas id="graph"></canvas>

<script>
    let myChart;

    $("#button").click(function() {
        if(Chart.getChart(myChart)) {
          myChart.destroy();
        }

        let ctx = $("#graph");
        myChart = new Chart(ctx, {/* My nice graph. */});
    });
</script>
```